# Displaying EditTextPreference current value in summary

Tags: android, summary, android-sharedpreferences, edittextpreference

I want to be able to display the value of an EditTextPreference in the summary field. Specifically, I want to do this within PreferenceFragmentCompat.

```
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Preference file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="DEVICE01"
        android:key="device_id"
        android:title="Device ID" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I have seen other solutions, but none of them included how to do this within PreferenceFragmentCompat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it's the same way as in every simple PreferenceFragment:
In xml file:

```
android:summary="@string/your_string_resource"
```

In code:

```
    EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(YOUR_PREFERENCE_KEY);
    editTextPreference.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(YOUR_PREFERENCE_KEY, defaultValue));
    editTextPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

            String yourString = o.toString();
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(YOUR_PREFERENCE_KEY, yourString).apply();
            editTextPreference.setSummary(yourString);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

As this question still pops up on Google, there is now a more direct way to solve this (using androidx).

```
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="prefFoobar"
        android:title="@string/preference_foobar"
        android:persistent="true"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The "app:useSimpleSummaryProvider" does all the magic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @grabarz121 set me in the right direction. This is what I added to the preferences:

```
android:summary="@string/pref_device_id_summary"
```

This is what I modified/added to the SettingsFragment class:

```
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    setDeviceIdSummary();
}

public void setDeviceIdSummary() {
    final String deviceIdKey = getString(R.string.pref_device_id_key);
    String deviceIdDefault = getString(R.string.pref_device_id_default);
    String deviceIdValue = sharedPreferences.getString(deviceIdKey, deviceIdDefault);

    final EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(deviceIdKey);
    editTextPreference.setSummary(deviceIdValue);

    editTextPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

            String newValue = o.toString();
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(deviceIdKey, newValue).apply();
            editTextPreference.setSummary(newValue);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```